# Adding an additional (second) OpenID causes a redirect to the root page, can we change that behavior?

Tags: feature-request, openid

When we add a secondary OpenID (for instance the newly minted openid.se) to our user account, we get directed to the front page. But for changing the existing primary OpenID, we get redirected to the user page.

I would like the semantics of adding a secondary to match the semantics of changing the primary. I have not tested the route of changing the secondary, because IIRC that can't be done.

The reason this matters is because I have decided to change my primary OpenID provider and to add a secondary one to all my accounts. Since I have to add the secondary one first, I keep getting redirected, so that adds an additional click, an additional pageview, and additional load not to mention the requisite 5 seconds or so for rendering and fetching so ... yes, this is a little bit of a whiny boy post (I admit it freely), but I think it is odd behavior that there are two different paths resulting from what appears to a user to be the same operation "alter my OpenID". Sorry for getting so verbose, but I wanted the user story to be more fully fleshed out.

Can we change where that redirect for adding a secondary OpenID lands the user?

***EDIT***

Apparently this is caused by using the Stack Exchange OpenID provider.